# Error using large Eigen matrix: " OBJECT_ALLOCATED_ON_STACK_IS_TOO_BIG"

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic, eigen

I have been using Eigen matrices to test a new code I wrote, and I just ran into this issue for the first time. I just started reading about "Fixed vs. Dynamic size" in Eigen matrices and I thought I was using "dynamic" matrices for large sizes, but when I try using larger number of grids I get the error:

```
 static assertion failed: OBJECT_ALLOCATED_ON_STACK_IS_TOO_BIG
```

Example code:

```
static const int nx = 128;
static const int ny = 128; 

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(){
Eigen::Matrix<double, (ny+1), nx> X; //ERROR HERE
X.setZero();
//other similar initializations 

}
```

This code is running fine for smaller sizes of `nx; ny;` but not the case I am showing. Ideally, I would like to run something as large as `nx=1024;` and `ny=1024;`
Is this not possible using Eigen matrices? Thanks.

Comment: Use `MatrixD(nx, ny)`. This should allocate on the heap. Matrices, where you specify the size in the template parameters, are allocated on the stack.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Sorry, could you elaborate? I am not seeing the difference b/w something like ``MatrixXd(nx,ny)`` and what I have. Thanks.

Comment: `Eigen::Matrix<double, (ny+1), nx> != Eigen::MatrixD(ny+1, nx)` I am not sure what I can elaborate here. I suggested to you to use a complete different class

Comment: You use the template parameters. For heap-allocated matrices, at least one of the two sizes is set to ```Eigen::Dynamic``` (-1) and then you specify the size in the constructor parameters. You set fixed sizes, resulting in stack allocation, which has a size limit. And as noted, ```Eigen::MatrixXd``` is a handy typedef for ```Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>```

Comment: Thanks everyone! Using ``Eigen::MatrixXd m(nx,ny)`` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people pointed out in the comments, using the following fixes the issue:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd
```

or

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>
```